# ocultar/mostrar div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou criando um site de uma agência de viagens, e no início do site eu criei 3 locais de destaque. Quando o usuário passar o *mouse* pelas imagens, a imagem deveria escurecer e aparecer *"mais detalhes"*. O problema é que não conseguindo ocultar/mostrar o div com css.

Segue, uma previa do site em questão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **p.s:** estava a utilizar a propriedade `visibility`.

Comment: coloca pelo menos a URL do site, mas de preferencia, coloque o codigo que voce esta usando... de uma forma a podermos verificar qual o problema... ou o que precisa ser feito

Comment: coloquei a function hide() para ocultar as divs ao retirar o mouse sobre as imagens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
//SCRIPT

function mostrar(obj) {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('div3').style.display="none";

  switch (obj.id) {
    case 'mostra1':
     document.getElementById('div1').style.display="block";
     break
    case 'mostra2':
     document.getElementById('div2').style.display="block";
     break
    case 'mostra3':
     document.getElementById('div3').style.display="block";
     break
  }
}
//função para ocultar as divs ao retirar o mouse sobre as imagens
function hide() {
       document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";
       document.getElementById('div2').style.display="none";
       document.getElementById('div3').style.display="none";
}
```

```css
//CSS

.imge {
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
   -o-transition: all 1s ease;
   -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
   transition: all 1s ease;
}
.imge:hover {
   -webkit-filter: brightness(10%);
   filter: brightness(10%);
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<a href="#" onmouseover="mostrar(this);" onmouseout="hide()" id="mostra1">
<img border="0" src="IMAGE1" class="imge"></a> 
<a href="#" onmouseover="mostrar(this);" onmouseout="hide()" id="mostra2">
<img border="0" src="IMAGE2" class="imge"></a> 
<a href="#" onmouseover="mostrar(this);" onmouseout="hide()" id="mostra3">
<img border="0" src="IMAGE3" class="imge"></a>

<div id="div1" style="display:none;">
   Descrição produto 1: 111111111111111111111111
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">
   Descrição produto 2: 222222222222222222222222
</div>
<div id="div3" style="display:none;">
   Descrição produto 3: 333333333333333333333333
</div>
```

Comment: Muito muito obrigado. Você ajudou-me muito. valeu :)